# Meteor._wrapAsync doesn't seem to work with stripe api library

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, stripe-payments

When I use `_wrapAsync` like so:

```
var stripeChargeCreate = Meteor._wrapAsync(_.bind(Stripe.charges.create,Stripe));
var charge = stripeChargeCreate({
    amount: amount,
    currency: "usd",
    card: token,
    description: description
});
```

I get the following error: Object # has no method 'createUrlData'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your bind is correct? `_.bind(Stripe.charges.create,Stripe.charges)` might work better.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Ironically, I actually tried this yesterday and it worked. But I had another error that I didn't read carefully enough.  Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction.

Comment: I had similar problems, and created a similar question, this is working in meteor > 0.9 maybe somebody can find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322617/meteor-wrapasync-dont-return-value