# Meteor.WrapAsync don't return value

Tags: javascript, meteor, stripe-payments

I been trying to make work `Meteor.WrapAsync` I have read [Meteor wrapAsync syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058205/meteor-wrapasync-syntax) answer, this video https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-meteor-wrapasync and I just cant figure how to `return` the response from the call from Stripe. I'm using `console.log` to print the steps, and I been reaching throw number 4 which mean, Im reaching `stripe` server and getting the response, but after that I can't see why `console.log(5)` its not printing. please if somebody can help me to understand why its the wrapAsyn its not returning the stripe callback?

```
    //this functions are part of an anonymous function and running in the server side of meteor
    stripe.charge = function (stripeToken) {
        // get a sync version of our API async func
        var strypeChargeSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(stripe.charge.process);

        // call the sync version of our API func with the parameters from the method call

        console.log("1");

        var response = strypeChargeSync(stripeToken);

        console.log("5" + response); ///// this never get print / log
        return response;
    }

    stripe.charge.process = function(stripeToken){
        var _stripe = StripeAPI(stripeKey);
        console.log("2");
        var charge = _stripe.charges.create({
            amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
            currency: "cad",
            card: stripeToken.id,
            description: "paid@whatever"
        }, function(err, charge) {
            if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
                alert("Sorry we couldn't charge the money: " + err);
                //console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log("4");
                //console.log(charge);
                return charge;
            }
        });
        console.log("3");
    }
```

//current output 1,2,3,4 but never 5 :(

EDIT

this is how I end having the Stripe function thanks for the support

```
    var syncFunction = Meteor.wrapAsync(_stripe.charges.create, _stripe.charges);
    var response = syncFunction({
        amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
        currency: "cad",
        card: stripeToken.id,
        description: "paid@whatever"
    });
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? I would guess it happens because you didn't bind the function to the object: `Meteor.wrapAsync(stripe.charge.process, stripe.charge)`

Comment: none errors,and also did that at the very beginning let me try it right now again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrapping the wrong function here, `Meteor.wrapAsync` transforms an async function (this means a function which transmits its result to the caller via a callback) in a synchronous one.

The function you pass to `Meteor.wrapAsync` does not have a callback as final argument, you should instead wrap `_stripe.charge.create`.

```
stripe.charge = function (stripeToken) {
  var _stripe = StripeAPI(stripeToken);
  var stripeChargeSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(_stripe.charge.create,_.stripe.charge);
  var response = stripeChargeSync({
    amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
    currency: "cad",
    card: stripeToken.id,
    description: "paid@whatever"
  });
  return response;
};
```

If you want to handle errors, you should use a `try`/`catch` block when calling `stripe.charge`.

```
try{
  stripe.charge(STRIPE_TOKEN);
}
catch(exception){
  console.log("Sorry we couldn't charge the money",exception);
}
```

I see you are logging your error using `alert`, are you trying to use `Meteor.wrapAsync` on the client ? `Meteor.wrapAsync` is meant to be used on the server because the environment needed to provide synchronous-looking execution is available in Node.js, not the browser.

Comment: man Im not kiddidng just right now I discover by my self this dumb mistake I was to write this answer but you did  it before thanks man you deserve the answer. this is gonna help a lot in the future to some body.

Comment: yes im using it on the server side, now everything is working perfectly thanks...

Comment: u cant get the full original error object though. My solution is pasted here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2774

Comment: This helped me greatly ! Thank you guys for this !